# How can I run Python code in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

I want to put my Python code in Ruby Module and run it, but I don't know how to import the Python stand-alone script into Ruby. The following are my code:

**Python code**

```
import ystockquote
import pprint
pprint.pprint(ystockquote.get_all('GOOG'))
```

**Ruby**

```
module PythonInRuby
require "rubypython"

RubyPython.start # start the Python interpreter

cPickle = RubyPython.import("cPickle")
p cPickle.dumps("Testing RubyPython.").rubify

RubyPython.stop # stop the Python interpreter
```

The problem is that between the `RubyPython.start` and `RubyPython.stop`, I don't know how to import the Python file. And another problem is what the code is for running Ruby in this module?

Comment: This is likely the most complicated and brittle way to solve this issue possible. Why do you want this?

Comment: Because I don't know how to get financial data using Ruby language.

Comment: Make a script in Python to get the financial data, and call it with a subprocess call from Ruby. Much easier.

Comment: So, I guess the next logical question is, if you know how to do it in Python, why do you need to use Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a completely overdone, over-complicated way to do this, but here's how anyway.

Say your python module (file) is named `googstock.py`. It should look like this:

```
import ystockquote

def run():
    return ystockquote.get_all('GOOG')
```

Then your Ruby can look like this:

```
RubyPython.start

googstock = RubyPython.import('googstock')
puts googstock.run().rubify #Get the stock data into Ruby

RubyPython.stop
```

In the future though, try just getting the stock values from Yahoo!'s API in Ruby. It can't be that hard.

Comment: Thanks so much, by the way, how can I run this ruby module on rails?

Comment: @user2668789: Depends where you're hosting the code. But for that, I suggest calling the API directly. This is not production ready, and for something so simple converting really is an option.